# Getting value from entry Tkinter widget for search in Arabic

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry, arabic-support

I am trying to make a search app which search for text in HTML files using BeautifulSoup to parse HTML files and get search keyword from Tkinter entry widget to search with. I used AwesomeTkinter to display Arabic correctly inside the Tkinter Entry widget. Text displays fine and the value is correct but I get no result, while entering the same value manually inside the code works fine. can anyone help me with that please?

Here is the code I used

```
def searchFiles():
    global searchFolderPath
    count = 0
    searched_word = searchField.get()
    print(searched_word)
    if not searched_word:
        print(searched_word)
        searchTree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=count, text="Please enter a search keyword first...")
    else:
        _, _, filenames_search = next(walk(searchFolderPath))
        results = {}
        for file in filenames_search:
            if file.split('.')[1] == 'html':
                soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open(f'{searchFolderPath}/{file}', encoding="utf-8"), 'html.parser')
                results = soup.body.find_all(string=re.compile('.*{0}.*'.format(searched_word)), recursive=True)
                if results:
                    searchTree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=count, text=file)
                    count += 1
        if not results:
            searchTree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=count, text="No Result")
```

and this is what I used to make Arabic letters display correctly

```
import tkinter as tk    
import awesometkinter as atk

searchField = tk.Entry(tab3, justify='right', width=50)
searchField.pack()
atk.add_bidi_support(searchField)
```

Comment: Your entry widget problem should be solved, all you need do is rename the components to fit your code.

Comment: @Derek what do you mean?

Comment: Your question pertains to `tkinter Entry` widgets and how to return text from it. My answer does that and also gives you a key `bind` method for convenience.

Comment: I have no problem getting the value in English, but there is a problem with the Arabic language, that's why I added "in Arabic" in my question.

Comment: If you are able to insert Arabic text into `Entry` widget then the code I have supplied will extract it. `Tkinter` has over 3000 ASC characters including simplified Chinese, Korean, Arabic, Cyrillic... Anything you can type into `Entry` can be retrieved from it.

Answer (score 0):

> Getting value from entry Tkinter widget

Use `searchField.get()` to return the value in the entry widget

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve text from `Entry` object try inserting the following code snippet.

I've renamed objects to conform to your code example.

```py
def getmyentry( ev ):
    print( var3.get() )

var3 = tk.StringVar()
searchField = tk.Entry(tab3, justify='right', width=50, textvariable = var3) 
searchField.pack()
bound = searchField.bind( "<Return>", getmyentry )
```

You can now enter text into your entry box and press Return key to retrieve it

Comment: This is going to raise an error. Move the `def getmyentry(...): ...` to the start of the code.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Converted this from a class.

Answer (score 0):

```
filenames_search = next(walk(searchFolderPath))

results = {""}


for file in filenames_search:


    if file.split('.')[1] == 'html':


        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open(f'{searchFolderPath}/{file}', encoding="utf-8"), 'html.parser')


        results = soup.body.find_all(string=re.compile('.*{0}.*'.format(searched_word)), recursive=True)


        if results:



            searchTree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=count, text=file)
            

            count += 1
```

## you are just typing code frequently just remember about the lines which is causing error try mine i managed code in a order!!